# Agregar un botón que me permita cargar mas campos de un formulario de gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, web, formularios, wordpress-theme, wordpress-plugin

Estoy haciendo un formulario en el cual una persona debe llenar unos datos personales, sin embargo en una de las secciones en las que la persona debe llenar la información de sus familiares necesito que el usuario tenga la capacidad de agregar por su cuenta los campos que necesite, ya que es imposible saber si la persona tiene 2,3 o 20 hermanos o hijos, por defecto dejaré 2 para padre y madre pero necesito que el usuario dinamicamente agrege mediante un boton los que necesite segun la cantidad de familiares que desee inscribir, esto lo estoy haciendo mediante Gravity Forms pero no encuentro la manera de hacer que cargue, ya que ademas cuando la persona termine su aplicación esta debe llegar a manera de PDF a las personas interesadas, esa parte ya la tengo funcionando pero no quiero afectar su funcionamiento si implemento algo adicional.

Link del formulario actual.
La seccion de interes es 3.Familiares(padres,hermanos (as) y /o hijos)
http://soledu.net/co/formulario-de-aplicacion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un plugin para hacer precisamente eso: https://wordpress.org/plugins/repeater-add-on-for-gravity-forms/